# Python read data from mysql errors

Tags: python-3.x, mysql5

I want read a column from mysql ,multiply a factor and write into mysql

```
cursor = db.cursor()
query = ('SELECT GDP FROM selectedairport')
cursor.execute(query)
gdp_list = []
for GDP in cursor:
    gdp_list.append(GDP)

weight = 0.5
num = gdp_list * weight
cursor.execute("UPDATE `selectedairport` SET `selectedairport`.`GDP`=num")
```

However,this produces the error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

And i find the gdp_list

```
[(50,),
 (60,),
 (80,),
 (40,)]
```

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a list by multiplying a list of numbers by a factor, you'd have to multiply each one individually, e.g.:

```
num = [g * weight for g in gdp_list]
```

But frankly, there's no reason to do that, or even to query the table apriori. You could just use the `update` statement to multiply a column by a factor directly:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE `selectedairport` SET `selectedairport`.`GDP`= `GDP` * 0.5)
```